# SQL server 2012 restore wizard freezes

Tags: sql-server

I have a development laptop with SSMS Express 2012 with a 2012 db instance and a 2008 db instance.  Have been using this configuration for over a year.  Suddenly I am unable to use the restore wizard.  The wizard will pick the backup file but when I select the "Files" option on the upper left to designate the location of the MDF and LDF the dialog hangs.  I tried a repair, no luck.

Comment: Why are you not using T-SQL script to restore ? Wizard does not have proper wisdom any more and so it hangs 

Comment: I have seen the restore wizard hang when an incorrectly formed backup files was selected in the past. Do a `RESTORE HEADERONLY`and `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` see if it works. Also, use T-SQL like @marko suggested.

Answer (score 62):

@Pat I have been facing the same issue for a long time, but a few minutes ago found way around it.

First of all DO NOT try to restore by right-clicking on an empty database. What you need to do is right-click on **Databases** and from the menu select **Restore Database**. In that UI you can use the *Files* option and the UI won't freeze.

Note: By doing this SQL will create your DB and restore into it in one go.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow...  Why down voting this answer.  After seamlessly trying to restore a backup on a newly created blank database I tried this as a last resort.  This is the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: Also don't know why this was downvoted. Successfully worked for me to after the same issue kept freezing SSMS 2014. I have also encountered this in SSMS 2012

Comment: +1 Works for me on SSMS 17.5 as well, on which I still see this problem when browsing for the backup files.

Comment: WWWWHYYYYYYYYYYYYYY?????

Comment: your solution saved my day, thanks !

Comment: +1 The behavior still occurs in SSMS v17.9 and your workaround saves my day!

Comment: Still occurs in v18.2.  How has MSFT not fixed this yet??  Thank you for the workaround!

Comment: Here I am in 2020, using SSMS 18, with this solution from 2016 being the only workaround...

Comment: worked perfectly, for me it was happenig in MSSQL 2017. Thnx

Answer (score 3):

You can try to restore via T-SQL. E.g.:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Full.BAK'
WITH
      REPLACE   -- Overwrite DB - if one exists
    , NORECOVERY    -- Use if DIFFs / T/Logs to recover
--      , RECOVERY  -- Use if NO more files to recover, database will be set ready to use
    , STATS = 10    -- Show progress (every 10%)
GO
```

As for the wizard error you can try to use [Windows Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) to try troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

I too had SSMS freeze immediately after selecting a database to restore.

The fix for me was simple, I just had to run SSMS as an Administrator.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today, trying to restore several files of database X as **a new database set as the destination.**

The problem in my case was that the backups were for a database X (Full+Diff+Logs), and there already was database X on the server, but the database was offline at the moment. That caused SMSS to freeze every time. So to solve this, I just temporarily brought database X back online, done the restore to a new database, and then took database X back offline.

Hopefully this might help someone experiencing this issue. **If the Restore Database dialog hangs and is not responding, check if there isn't an offline database with the same name as the one in the backups.**

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem even when not using the wizard, using a script similar to Marko's running through SSMS it would freeze and crash the machine. The way I resolved it was to drop the DB first, then I found the .ldf to still be in the target directory, removed the .ldf from the target directory and was able to restore successfully.